# Should application name relate to application icon?

Tags: icons

Should my application name relate to app icon? For example if I want to name my application apple should the icon be an apple icon?

Comment: Fundamentally, this feels like a branding/marketing question. If a UI designer were to solely use his priorities in determining the icon, I don't think he'd be doing it justice.

Comment: Pretty much what Rahul said. This is a bigger picture question that should incorporate a broader marketing/branding initiative. In general, yea, he icon should somehow relate to the app as should the name, but good branding may trump that.

Answer (score 5):

It depends.  Ideally, what the application does would be something related to "Apple", so the name, function, and icon are all aligned.

However, if your "Apple" application is used for, say, painting, a paint icon might work better.  Then it becomes your decision on whether to align the icon with the application's name or the application's function.

Answer (score 2):

I concur Hisham. It really depends. I recommend this book:
iPhone and iPad Apps Marketing: Secrets to Selling Your iPhone and iPad Apps (Que Biz-Tech)

There's a section on this which I find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should, because this way it supports the user remembering the app. I can remember the name and the icon an associate it easily.

Answer (score 1):

The app name, icon, and even the installation file should all be considered in the use of the product.